# aws s3 object permissions via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I can set the Permissions on an Object via AWS S3, clicking on the object, selecting Permissions (e.g. Grantee and Open/Download).

However, I can't seem to see these permissions via the `s3api`. E.g. if I run

```
aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket <my bucket> --key <my file>
```

I get:

```
An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObjectAcl operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What value did you specify for `<my file>`. No need to give the actual value.

Comment: --key numbers3.txt

Comment: Is there an object named `numbers3.txt` in `my-bucket`?

Comment: Having the same issue only when I try to find out what the permissions are for a particular "folder" but it works when I try it on a file.  The issue with this folder is that it was created via a script and not manually, any other folder I try to get the acl for it works.

Answer (score 0):

That command works fine for me when I use my own **bucket name** and **key**.

Some things to check:

- Does the bucket exist?
- Does the key exist?
- Do you have permission to call `GetObjectAcl` on this bucket?